# Polars-python replace string in multiple columns

Tags: python, python-polars

getting the following error "with_columns() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given". When I replace string with just one column it works, however want to replace multiple strings.

simplified example of want I want to do

```
import polars as pl 
df = pl.DataFrame({"id": [1, 2,3,4,5], "text": ["abc", "abc","cde","cde","fgh"]})
df2=df.with_columns(
    pl.col("text").str.replace(r"abc", "ABC"),
    pl.col("text").str.replace(r"cde", "CDE"),
    pl.col("text").str.replace(r"fgh", "FGH"))
```

Comment: I think you need to pass that as a list instead of separate arguments.

Comment: Passing multiple arguments to `.with_columns` was added in `0.16.3` - you can chain `.str.replace().str.replace()` if that's what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple, use a list of expressions within with_columns:

```
df2=df.with_columns(
    [
        pl.col("text").str.replace(r"abc", "ABC"),
        pl.col("text").str.replace(r"cde", "CDE"),
        pl.col("text").str.replace(r"fgh", "FGH")
    ]
)
```

Here some other tips:

I do not get exactly what you need but instead of using replace, you can use use to_uppercase():

```
df2=df.with_columns(
    [
        pl.col("text").str.to_uppercase()
    ]
)
```

tip 2)

you can chain replace() as suggested by [jqurious](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19355181/jqurious)

```
df2=df.with_columns(
    [
        pl.col("text").str.replace(r"abc", "ABC").str.replace(r"cde", "CDE").replace(r"fgh", "FGH")
    ]
)
```

tip 3)

If you want to work on the text column based on a condition, use pl.when for example

```
        pl.when(pl.col('text').str == 'abc')
        .then('ABC')
        .when(pl.col('text').str == 'cde')
        .then('CDE')
        .when(pl.col('text').str == 'fgh')
        .then('FGH')
        .otherwise('Unknown')
```